# How do I solve a KeyError when importing a python module?

Tags: python, module, path, python-import, keyerror

I was trying to import a module from a different directory level so I used:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
```

But now I get this error. I'm using Spyder and the first time I use the following import, it works fine.

```
from source.search.ci_search_project import CI_Search_Project
```

From the second time I get this error.

> File "ipython-input-29-f35dfe634c32", line 1, in module
> >runfile('C:/Users/nrshakya/Documents/CI/src/Comp_IntelPython/ci_search_project_test.py', wdir='C:/Users/nrshakya/Documents/CI/src/Comp_IntelPython')

> File "C:\Users\nrshakya\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
> execfile(filename, namespace)

> File "C:\Users\nrshakya\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
> exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

> File "C:/Users/nrshakya/Documents/CI/src/Comp_IntelPython/ci_search_project_test.py", line 8, in module
> from source.search.ci_search_project import CI_Search_Project

> File "frozen importlib._bootstrap", line 961, in _find_and_load

> File "frozen importlib._bootstrap", line 946, in _find_and_load_unlocked

> File "frozen importlib._bootstrap", line 885, in _find_spec

> File "frozen importlib._bootstrap_external", line 1157, in find_spec

> File "frozen importlib._bootstrap_external", line 1123, in _get_spec

> File "frozen importlib._bootstrap_external", line 994, in **iter**

> File "frozen importlib._bootstrap_external", line 982, in _recalculate

> File "frozen importlib._bootstrap_external", line 978, in _get_parent_path

> KeyError: 'source'

Comment: Please post the code required to reproduce the problem!

Comment: I added it to the main question. 
it's just an import:
from source.search.ci_search_project import CI_Search_Project

Comment: Has anyone found a resolution to this? I'm encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

[According to Vera's answer to their question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53855836/keyerror-frozen-importlib-bootstrap-error-on-second-library-import-in-spyder), adding an empty `__init__.py` file in the folder containing the module will fix this problem.