# Django and "OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect" when using venv virtual environment

Tags: python, django, virtual-environment

I am building a website in django and using a python venv in my development environment. When I tried to run 'python manage.py runserver' I got the error below. I have used this venv virtual enviroment in my project before without any problems. Does anyone know why I might be getting the error below? If so, does anyone know how I might be able to fix this?

As an fyi, I am developing on a windows machine.

```
(.venv) PS C:\Users\username> python manage.py runserver 
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\username\\.venv\\Lib\\site-packages'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\username\manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1138, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1078, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1504, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1476, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1616, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1659, in _fill_cache
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\username\\.venv\\Lib\\site-packages'
```

I've tried searching for help with no success yet unfortunately.

Comment: is there a  `__init__.py` file in the sub-directory folder?
Saw a similar situation on Stack Overflow -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53855836/keyerror-frozen-importlib-bootstrap-error-on-second-library-import-in-spyder

Comment: @Ishaan Adarsh thank you for your suggestion. I looked into this and it unfortunately didn't solve my issue. I then reviewed every third party package that was installed in my phython/django project by installing them individually into a new virtual environment. I was eventually able to recreate the error and found that I needed to update the 'docxtpl' package and it's dependencies to the most current version. Once I did this the error that I had originally asked for help with went away.

Comment: Great. you should post this answer on this post. It might be helpful for someone running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

As an update, I was able to fix the issue. I reviewed every third party package that was installed in my python/django project by installing them individually into a new virtual environment. I was eventually able to recreate the error and found that I needed to update the 'docxtpl' package and it's dependencies to the most current version. Once I did this the error that I had originally asked for help with went away.